# ¿Se dice "La tierra 'sentía' o 'se sentía' húmeda y fría"?

Tags: verbos, reflexivos

¿Cuál de estas frases es correcta?

> La tierra **sentía** húmeda y fría
>
> La tierra **se sentía** húmeda y fría

La frase es dicha por un personaje que narra en primera persona.

Answer (score 6):

Existen dos formas correctas. Usar la voz activa o la voz pasiva:

Si el personaje dice:

> (Yo) Sentía la tierra fría y húmeda.

En este caso la persona que lo dice utiliza la voz activa. Voz Activa: "se conjuga el verbo de modo tal que el sujeto realice, ejecute o controle la acción del verbo, es decir, sea sujeto agente."

Si el personaje dice:

> La tierra se sentía fría y húmeda.

En este caso la persona que lo dice utiliza la voz pasiva. Voz Pasiva: "se presenta al sujeto como pasivo (sujeto paciente)"

Answer (score 2):

La primera no tiene sentido.

Puedes sustituir *tierra* por *ella* para que resulte más fácil:

> Ella se sentía húmeda y fría.

Comment: ustadra: gracias por tu respuesta y bienvenido/a al sitio. ¿Podrías aportar más datos al respecto? Siguiendo lo aconsejado en [answer], edita la publicación para incluir más referencias y explicaciones que hagan más útil tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No hubiera elegido 'sentir'. Son ambas correctas.

Mi manera de decirlo:

> La tierra parecía húmeda y fría

Comment: You are right that the first sentence is wrong but you are wrong about the meaning of the second sentence. The second sentences is completely right and valid. It does not mean that _the ground felt_ but it means **you** felt the sensation when touching the ground

Comment: @DGaleano How would you then say that the ground experienced a feeling of cold?

Comment: The ground does not experience sensations. People do. You are right it sounds like if the ground was feeling but we use the reflexive a lot for this. It's called passive voice...and there is a new answer that is addressing it.

Comment: As your profile is not completed we can't know your background. Notice this question was made in Spanish so the answer should be also in Spanish. Please try re-writing it.  It is good if you tell us something about yourself on the profile so we better understand you and be more helpful.

Comment: I flatly admit it is not my first language. Sorry for misleading people. I thought this was a text book case; I was unaware of the extent of my ignorance.

Comment: You are doing ok and don't worry, it is not misleading. We native speakers don't know everything and sometimes people that have learned Spanish have some great contributions and something to learn too and that's why we are here. To learn. :-)